# WiFi doesn't work when SuperSU 2.72 binaries are installed on Android 7

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi, rooting, 7.0-nougat

Since a few days I have Cyanogenmod 14 for my Samsung SM-G900f. I want to use some apps by Chainfire but they all require his su binaries so I tried to install it via the SuperSU app, which always fails, and via TWRP, which then worked.
After flashing it I noticed that I when I turn on WiFi that it just scans but nothing appears; even the already saved networks won't show up. I also tried connecting via WPS pin and WPS push, but it just gives me an error message.

Does somebody have any idea what the cause might be?

Comment: Try the latest SuperSu Beta: http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/supersu/2014-09-02-supersu-v2-05-t2868133

Comment: It didn't work. Same results.

Comment: Better you uninstall SuperSu app and binaries and use CM's Default Root Access (from Developer Settings) till the issue is fixed..

Answer (score 1):

On 30 Nov, 2016, [Chainfire Releases SuperSU v2.78 SR5, Fixing Some Nougat Bugs](https://www.xda-developers.com/chainfire-releases-supersu-v2-78-sr5-fixing-some-nougat-bugs/)

> Today, he has released yet another update to SuperSU, and this one focuses on some Nougat related bugs again. In a Google+ post, Chainfire tells us that some scripts and services weren’t able to be executed thanks to some modifications SuperSU makes to SELinux and the stricter service execution rules in Nougat. This didn’t happen on all firmwares, but this did lead to Wi-Fi, cellular, and other modem-related features not working on some of them (like the Samsung Nougat beta and CyanogenMod 14.1).
>
> [...]
>
> You can download the [new version of SuperSU here](http://download.chainfire.eu/1014/SuperSU/SR5-SuperSU-v2.78-SR5-20161130091551.zip), [...]