# Uninstall SuperSu with binaries

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi, supersu

I have Cyanogenmod 14.1 installed on my Samsung SM-G900f. After installing SuperSu from Phillz recovery, Wifi try to start, but no success. I found the same post here [WiFi doesn't work when SuperSU 2.72 binaries are installed on Android 7](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/161353/wifi-doesnt-work-when-supersu-2-72-binaries-are-installed-on-android-7?newreg=a413e9de1352448cb64d9d4b2b60aa3c)

The last comment sugest to "Better you uninstall SuperSu app and binaries and use CM's Default Root Access (from Developer Settings) till the issue is fixed"

I've tried to uninstall SuperSu the normal way and from the app settings: SuperSu > Settings > Switch superuser app, but when SuperSu is uninstalled and in the CM settings the root access is set to disabled, it is ignored and every app that granted root permission from SuperSu before, seems it has it now and use it without asking.
Root access from CM settings is ignored.

That being said, how can I uninstall SuperSu app and binaries and use CM's Default Root Access? 
Or even better, is there a fix to a non working Wifi?

Answer (score 0):

If the SuperSU app to remove SuperSU binary doesn't work, you'll have to wipe and reinstall but fear not as this will not wipe your user data.

Make sure to have the cm rom for your device and google apps if needed.

Now that you have them, preferably in your device for easier access, boot your device into recovery.

In your custom recovery you should select the wipe option>advanced wipe options>select **only** system and wipe it.

After this you just flash CyanogenMod normally, and Gapps if needed, reboot your device and that should be all.

PD. Is always good to make a backup.

Answer (score -1):

Today, SuperSu released a new version with a fix for wifi https://download.chainfire.eu/1014/SuperSU/SR5-SuperSU-v2.78-SR5-20161130091551.zip